# Why doesn't this query use the indexes i've created?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Running postgres 9.5

```
SELECT events.id, events.start_time, events.host_id, events.title from events
JOIN accountsevents ON accountsevents.events_id = events.id
WHERE accountsevents.accounts_id = %(account_id)s OR events.host_id = %(account_id)s
GROUP BY events.id
ORDER BY start_time DESC
```

I have this query and postgres says the cost is over 100k. Seems excessive. This is the only query I have that isn't utilizing the indexes i've created for each table.

```
Indexes:
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "events_host_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (host_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "accountsevents" CONSTRAINT "accountsevents_events_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (events_id) REFERENCES events(id)
    TABLE "eventsinterests" CONSTRAINT "eventsinterests_events_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (events_id) REFERENCES events(id)


Indexes:
    "accountsevents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, accounts_id, events_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "accountsevents_accounts_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (accounts_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
    "accountsevents_events_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (events_id) REFERENCES events(id)
```

I feel like the index is setup wrong or I'm just missing something with the query. The initial sequence scans are killing it.

ADDED EXPLAIN VERBOSE

```
"Sort  (cost=124388.27..124390.10 rows=732 width=40) (actual time=1533.902..1533.928 rows=470 loops=1)"
"  Output: events.id, events.start_time, events.host_id, events.title"
"  Sort Key: events.start_time DESC"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 66kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=124346.12..124353.44 rows=732 width=40) (actual time=1533.658..1533.759 rows=470 loops=1)"
"        Output: events.id, events.start_time, events.host_id, events.title"
"        Group Key: events.id"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=4912.30..124344.29 rows=732 width=40) (actual time=56.671..1532.831 rows=971 loops=1)"
"              Output: events.id, events.start_time, events.host_id, events.title"
"              Hash Cond: (accountsevents.events_id = events.id)"
"              Join Filter: ((accountsevents.accounts_id = 1) OR (events.host_id = 1))"
"              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2761882"
"              ->  Seq Scan on public.accountsevents  (cost=0.00..45228.52 rows=2762852 width=8) (actual time=0.005..466.094 rows=2762853 loops=1)"
"                    Output: accountsevents.events_id, accountsevents.accounts_id"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=2795.91..2795.91 rows=104191 width=40) (actual time=53.579..53.579 rows=104181 loops=1)"
"                    Output: events.id, events.start_time, events.host_id, events.title"
"                    Buckets: 65536  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 2462kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.events  (cost=0.00..2795.91 rows=104191 width=40) (actual time=0.004..26.171 rows=104181 loops=1)"
"                          Output: events.id, events.start_time, events.host_id, events.title"
"Planning time: 0.201 ms"
"Execution time: 1534.024 ms"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I've added the explain

Comment: Looks like you have a index on 3 columns and you use only 2 columns in the query. The index requires all 3. (id, accounts_id, events_id) I'd use id as primary key index and add another one for accounts_id & events_id.

Comment: what is `accountsevents.accounts_id = %(account_id)s`  ?? Looks like you are trying to use `LIKE` ?

Comment: It's the primary key integer for the accounts table row

Comment: You have no index on `events.host_id` and the one you have on `accountsevents` doesn't have the `accounts_id` at the first position so it's not being used for a condition on `accounts_id`. Try an index on `events (host_id)` and one on `accountsevents(accounts_id)`

Comment: Hmmm no dice. Still sequence scans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No index will help you with this query.

The problem is that you have an `OR` in the `WHERE` condition, so it is not possible to apply a filter *before* the tables are joined, which is where an index could help you. Try to replace the `OR` with an `AND` and see how PostgreSQL can do much better.

This way PostgreSQL has to compute the whole join and can only filter out rows afterwards – see the great number of *Rows Removed by Join Filter*.

The only thing an index could be used for would be a nested loop join, and that would be much more expensive. So I don't think that there is a better plan for this query.

You can see that PostgreSQL's estimates of the number of rows is pretty good, which is normally a sign that PostgreSQL indeed did the right thing.

Maybe you can do better with a query like

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT ... FROM events JOIN accountsevents ON ...
       WHERE accountsevents.accounts_id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT ... FROM events JOIN accountsevents ON ...
       WHERE events.host_id = 1) sub
GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ...
```

but I wouldn't bet on it.
(Note: this query is semantically slightly different, but maybe it doesn't matter in your case.)